# AngularJS todo example delete row after pushing/removing from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two separate containers: one for outstanding tasks and one for completed tasks.

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, task) in requirements.tasks.outstanding track by $index">
    <span class="handle"> <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-inline" ng-model="completionOutstanding" ng-checked="task.completed" ng-change="taskChange(task, key)">
            <i></i> </label> </span>
    <p>
        {{task.name}} <br />
        <span class="text-muted">{{task.description}}</span>
        <span class="date">{{task.date_entered}}</span>
    </p>
</li>
```

Markup augmented with Angular for completed tasks:

```
<li class="complete" ng-repeat="(key, task) in requirements.tasks.completed track by $index">
    <span class="handle"> <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-inline" ng-model="completionCompleted" ng-checked="task.completed" ng-change="taskChange(task, key)">
            <i></i> </label> </span>
    <p>
        {{task.name}} <br />
        <span class="text-muted">{{task.description}} </span>
        <span class="date">{{task.date_entered}}</span>
    </p>
</li>
```

Angular Controller `taskChange` function used:

```
$scope.taskChange = function(task, key) {

    if(task.completed == false) {
        task.completed = true;
        $scope.requirements.tasks.completed.push(task);
        delete $scope.requirements.tasks.outstanding[key];
    } else {
        task.completed = false;
        $scope.requirements.tasks.outstanding.push(task);
        delete $scope.requirements.tasks.completed[key];
    }


}
```

The functionality is working as it should, however, the row in the actual view persists.  The row along with the data should be removed, but when this is tested the row remains there.  As I add/remove tasks, many rows are accrued.

How can I add and remove the HTML rows in the list while adding/removing my data?

JSON Schema:

```
{
  "tasks": {
    "outstanding":[
     {}, {}, {}, {}
     ],
    "completed":[
     {}, {}, {}, {}
     ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Bindings should handle this for you, not sure about using delete on an array element though since it leaves an empty spot in the array you may need to use splice or lodash _.remove instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing Arrays and Objects in your code:

For an object use:

```
<!-- repeat attr -->
ng-repeat="(key, value) in items"

// add an item
items[key] = value;

// remove an item
delete items[key];
```

For an array:

```
<!-- repeat attr -->
ng-repeat="item in items"

// add an item
items.push(item);

// remove an item
items.slice(items.indexOf(item), 1);
```

Comment: This is an array of objects.

Comment: Added JSON Schema to the OP.  There are two arrays of objects, one for completed and one for outstanding.

Comment: Problem was arising from something else so since you have the correct answer I marked it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using delete to remove item from old list, that will not remove the "slot" of the item in the array, just set it to undefined
e.g. [a, b, c], after delete b, it becomes [a, undefined, c]

You may want to try splice to remove the item from array

Comment: Nope, he's using a hash, not an array.

Comment: well... he thinks he is... haha. that's the problem.

Comment: I'm still getting undesired results trying both.